# How to make work DataTables with Natural sort plugin?

Tags: jquery, datatables, natural-sort

I've seen some similar questions, but no correct answer in my case.

I use the [DataTables](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html) plugin to sort some tables.

But we can't sort datas like numerics while they are not (nut ;-p).
For example, we can't sort formatted prices like those :

- 2 150 000 €
- 4 500 000 €
- 225 000 €

So I tried to include a [DataTables plugin](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting) called "[Natural sort](http://www.overset.com/2008/09/01/javascript-natural-sort-algorithm-with-unicode-support/)".
But it doesn't seems to work, I may do some mistakes, but I can't find them.

Any help will be appreciated.

All you need to see/test it : **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DzaQe/1/)** (try to sort the columns...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like you have two problems. First, dT isn't picking up your custom sort - it's just ignoring it and using the standard sort. I was able to fix this by specifying the sort for each column:

```
$('#table_list').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [null, {"sType": "natural"}, null, null],
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    "sScrollX": "100%",
});
```

Second, natural sort won't sort those numbers the way you expect. It will take the first number section up until the space and sort on that, like so:

```
2 150 000 €
4 750 000 €
210 000 €
```

So you probably just want to write your own sort. Here's an example I tried:

```
function testSort( a, b ) {
    var aa = a.replace(/[ \.]/g,''), bb = b.replace(/[ \.]/g,'');
    aa = parseInt( aa.substring( 0, aa.length - 1 ) );
    bb = parseInt( bb.substring( 0, bb.length - 1 ) );
    return aa == bb ? 0 : ( aa < bb ? -1 : 1 );
}
```

The key is removing the spaces, periods and euro signs so that it can be read as a number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried it http://jsfiddle.net/DzaQe/2/ but it seems to be inoperative too. The function naturalSort(a,b) doesn't do the work ? you can see examples here http://www.overset.com/2008/09/01/javascript-natural-sort-algorithm-with-unicode-support/ I think that there is something wrong with the plugin call "jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['natural-...']" and not sure that {"sType": "natural"} is the right syntax too...

Comment: None of the examples on that page sort regular numbers that have thousands separators. I looked at your fiddle; you need to `return testSort( a, b );` instead of calling `testSort` and then `return naturalSort( a, b );`. I also updated my code since you changed your thousands separators from ` ` to `.`.

Comment: Here, I forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v2L4T/1/ Using `testSort` for the price column, and `naturalSort` for the rest.

Comment: Oh thanks +1 for your help. I've found another way to do it also. But yours seems to be code lighter :-) Any idea to implement testSort() into naturalSort() ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ryan P my sType declarations were wrong...

Finaly, I needed to add more plugins to make it work, I share it if it can help someone :

- Natural sort : for the varchar values

> ```
> jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['natural-asc']  = function(a,b) {
>     return naturalSort(a,b);
> };
>
> jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['natural-desc'] = function(a,b) {
>     return naturalSort(a,b) * -1;
> };
> ```

- Unshift "null" types into formated-num :

> ```
> jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.aTypes.unshift(  
>     function ( sData )  
>     {  
>         var deformatted = sData.replace(/[^\d\-\.\/a-zA-Z]/g,'');
>         if ( $.isNumeric( deformatted ) ) {
>             return 'formatted-num';
>         }
>         return null;  
>     }  
> );
> ```

- Formatted-num : for... formated numbers values

> ```
> jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['formatted-num-asc'] = function(a,b) {
>     /* Remove any formatting */
>     var x = a.match(/\d/) ? a.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" ) : 0;
>     var y = b.match(/\d/) ? b.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" ) : 0;
>
>     /* Parse and return */
>     return parseFloat(x) - parseFloat(y);
> };
>
> jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['formatted-num-desc'] = function(a,b) {
>     var x = a.match(/\d/) ? a.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" ) : 0;
>     var y = b.match(/\d/) ? b.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" ) : 0;
>
>     return parseFloat(y) - parseFloat(x);
> };
> ```

Working example here : http://jsfiddle.net/DzaQe/3/