# Datatables: Need to sort a column numerically by data in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a table that looks like this...

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="site.com?id=1">1</a></td>
        <td>Foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="site.com?id=9">9</a></td>
        <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="site.com?id=10">10</a></td>
        <td>Baz</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to make it so my [Bootstrap Datatables](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting) scripting will sort by the inner HTML of the anchor tag, and sort it numerically.  Currently it is sorting it like this...

```
1   Foo
10  Baz
9   Bar
```

But I need it to be sorted like this...

```
1   Foo
9   Bar
10  Baz
```

I'm not really sure how to go about this.  I have it sorting, but it thinks the inner HTML is a string, not a number :(

Comment: This might be a duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305552/how-to-make-work-datatables-with-natural-sort-plugin

Comment: According to the page you linked to, "Data can often be a complicated mix of numbers and letters (file names are a common example) and sorting them in a natural manner is quite a difficult problem. Fortunately a deal of work has already been done in this area by other authors - the following plug-in uses the naturalSort() function by Jim Palmer (download it here) to provide natural sorting in DataTables." It looks like that page lists various methods for handling that situation.

Comment: I'm assuming this is with server-side data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are generating your links server-side.  You are better off rendering these on the client for two reasons:

1. Your sort will work
2. Your payload will be smaller

To do this you need to use aoColumnsDef and aTargets similar to the below

```
    "aoColumnDefs": [
    {
        "aTargets": [ 1 ],
        "fnRender": function ( o, val ) {
          var link = "<a class='' href='site.com?id=" + o.aData[0] + "'>" + o.aData[0] + "</a>";
          return link;
        }
    },
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is useful, thanks, but it does not sort.  Is it possible to have it both sort and render?  I tried bSortable: true, but it does nothing.

Comment: Okay I figured it out, you need to use: bUseRendered : false

Thanks!

Comment: This depends on the end user's browser - one of the beauties of DataTables is that it degrades gracefully - if JS is turned off on the browser, it will just display a standard HTML table. With your solution, the plain HTML table will not contain the links. This might also cause issues for robots crawling the page...